# ILMerge - breaking reflection?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, ilmerge

I have been running into a problem lately (not noticed before) where merging 2 assemblies results in one or more types that have 'lost' their base type (System.Object) - breaking any attempt at using reflection either within or outside of the resulting assembly.

Both assemblies are .NET 4.5 based, the primary assembly is an ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  I was able to work around the reflection issue prior to employing the new Web API and its associated dependency resolver (hence the reflection that I have no control over).

Please note that the merge itself had no errors \ problems, targeting the correct v4;[Program Files - referenced assemblies], AnyCPU-based, etc, etc (I am almost 100% sure that I have covered all the cases - might be wrong:))

Has anyone else encountered this?  How can I resolve this issue?

Edit: 20 March 2013

ILMerge version 2.13.307.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2004-2006. All rights reserved.
ILMerge /ndebug /useFullPublicKeyForReferences /keyfile:[pathToSNK] /log:output.log /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /lib:[ManyOfThese] /align:4096 /out:[Target].dll [Source].dll [ToMerge].dll

Set platform to 'v4', using directory 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319' for mscorlib.dll
Running on Microsoft (R) .NET Framework v4.0.30319
mscorlib.dll version = 4.0.0.0
The list of input assemblies is: [Source].dll, [ToMerge].dll

-Trying to read assembly from the file '[Source].dll'.
Successfully read in assembly.
There were no errors reported in [Source]'s metadata.
-Trying to read assembly from the file '[ToMerge].dll'.
Successfully read in assembly.
There were no errors reported in [ToMerge]'s metadata.
-Checking to see that all of the input assemblies have a compatible PeKind.
[Source].PeKind = ILonly
[ToMerge].PeKind = ILonly
-All input assemblies have a compatible PeKind value.
[A number of AssemblyResolver sections, each ending in success]

-Using assembly '[Source]' for assembly-level attributes for the target assembly.
-Merging assembly '[Source]' into target assembly.
-Merging assembly '[ToMerge]' into target assembly.
-Duplicate type name: modifying name of the type '[SomeAnonymousType]' (from assembly '[ToMerge]') to '[ToMerge].[SomeAnonymousType]'
-Copying 1 Win32 Resources from assembly '[Source]' into target assembly.
-ILMerge: Signing assembly with the key file ':[pathToSNK]'.
There were no errors reported in the target assembly's metadata.
-ILMerge: Writing target assembly '[Target].dll'.
[A number of AssemblyResolver sections, each ending in success]

-ILMerge: Signed assembly '[Source].dll' with a strong name.
[A number of locations with no errors]

-ILMerge: Done.

PEVerify.exe /MD /IL [Target].dll
35 Error(s) (212 Warnings).

Comment: What does PEVerify say on the merged assembly? Have you tried with an older version of ILMerge?

Comment: i feel your ilmerge pain. haven't had this particular issue but i did have an issue upgrading a .net 4.0 to .net 4.5 application that was using ILMerge. since some of the assemblies are 4.0 and yours are 4.5 i'd make absolute sure that you're providing the correct parameters to ilmerge

Comment: PEVerify has a number of "[MD]: Error: TypeDef that is not an Interface and not the Object class extends Nil token." and even more "[MD]: Warning: MemberRef has a duplicate, token=0x0a00034e." - 14 Errors and 221 Warnings - Ouch:(.  I was using the last installable version from Microsoft prior to moving the latest version - hoping that it would solve the problem - unfortunately without luck.

Comment: Thanks David.  I have looked at the log files and it seems to be picking up the correct assembly references (under \Program Files, versus under \Windows\Microsoft.NET).  The only suspect statement had to do with copying a Win32 resource - this I am unable to find.